# How to change custom viewForHeaderInSection width after rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have to build a custom tableViewHeader in which at least two labels should be displayed, viz. a projectName and projectDescription.  The contents of these two labels vary (i.e. in terms of string-length).

I managed to get a working version for the default device orientation (portrait) but if the user rotates the device to landscape the width of my custom headerView is not adjusted, and the user will see unused white space to the right.

The following code fragment is being used:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50.0f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    CGFloat wd = tableView.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat ht = tableView.bounds.size.height;
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0., 0., wd, ht)];
    headerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    // Add project name/description as labels to the headerView.
    UILabel *projName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5., 5., wd, 20)];
    UILabel *projDesc = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5., 25., wd, 20)];
    projName.text = @"Project: this project is about an interesting ..";
    projDesc.text = @"Description: a very long description should be more readable when your device is in landscape mode!";
    [headerView addSubview:projName];
    [headerView addSubview:projDesc];
    return headerView;
}
```

I noticed that the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` will only be called once after `viewDidLoad`, but not after a device orientation change.

Should I implement the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method with something like:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.tableView reloadSections:nil withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

I cannot figure out how to get the `reloadSections:` to work, forcing a recalculation of my customView.

Answer (score 7):

If you use autoresizingMask the header adjusts correctly on rotation. No need to override anything else. I would set the automasks at the end of the code just before returning the view:

```
    [headerView addSubview:projName];
    [headerView addSubview:projDesc];
    projName.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    projDesc.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    headerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    return headerView;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for Swift 5.1 and the "tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)" method.